# Is laravel middleware necessary even though there is navigation guard in vuejs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am currently working on a project with Vuejs and Laravel. A single page application. I have already implemented navigation guard to restrict certain user to access to another page. So, for more security is Laravel middleware necessary to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary. The Vue Guard is just preventing the user to navigate to some page. But without a security middleware, anyone could make requests to the server and use your api easily.

Comment: Yes, i'm on my way to the office right now, and as soon as i get there, i'll post here.

Comment: Just to check your level of knowledge, do you understand clearly the difference between back-end and front-end ?

Comment: Late reply because i was sick. Not really because i directly learned vuejs without the baisc knowledge of js. Also i just know the very basic knowledge of HTML CSS and Bootstrap.  Resource please?